# Vscode Typescript: Display alias of type rather than its definition

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have the following code

```
type Opaque<T,U> = T & {_:U};
type EKey = Opaque<number,'EKey'>;
type AKey = Opaque<EKey,'AKey'>;
type PKey = Opaque<AKey,'PKey'>;

let a = <PKey>1;
let b:EKey = a;
```

When I move over `a`, I'd like it to show `PKey` instead of `Opaque<Opaque<Opaque<"EKey">,"AKey">,"PKey">`.

[image]

Is there a way to do this using built-in vscode options or by writing my own vscode extension using the vscode API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the quick info by writing your own typescript language server plugin and overwriting `getQuickInfoAtPosition`.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
type alias<t> = t & { _:never }
type my_type = alias<number | "or" | {"any other": "type you want"}>
```

Comment: In TS5, this gives me `type my_type = (number | { "any other": "type you want";} | "or") & { _: never;}`. This does not seem to be what the question asked for, is it? Please update your answer and highlight how it addresses the question.

Comment: @MoritzRingler I found out that definition of alias type must be inside scopes there it is used, i.e.
`function a() { let a: alias<1> } type alias<t> = t & { alias: alias<t> }`
gives that you described because of alias type defined outside of function "a", and
`function a() { let a: alias<1>; type alias<t> = t & { alias: alias<t> } }`
works as expected. vscode version 1.76.2